# image style not working after injected html <img src tag

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Que Tal!

Podría alguien ayudarme con este tema?

Tengo un web con un slider al frente que presenta 5 imagenes fijas y las cuales quiero asignar mediante un índice aleatorio. 
Al avanzar hacia abajo la pagina, tengo otra galería de 20 imágenes. En ambos casos me interesa sustituir en forma aleatoria cada imagen mediante refresh(f5) o mediante un botón; con sus respectivos títulos y comentarios.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con el primer elemento del slider, y mediante un poco de ayuda, ya inserta el HTML correpondiente al titulo en este caso el tag "p" también se incluye img src, ambos asignados por innerHTML en forma aleatoria.

El problema es que al sustituir el HTML, la imagen se reduce a 1/8, es decir no cubre la pantalla con la altura indicada. Es como si estuviese tomando el tamaña de las imágenes de la segunda galería. "p" funciona perfecto al tamaño indicado sin problemas. Ambos elementos se eligen en forma aleatoria correctamente.

Se desea usar JavaScript. conservando css, html5 y bootstrap. Para mayor claridad visitar: cienciaybelleza.com

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda.

De antemano gracias.

Para el slider son 5 divs como la siguiente, cada una con un "p" y un "img src", que deberán ser sustituidos utilizando un índice generado en forma aleatoria, de acuerdo a la función que se anexa.

```
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="layera">
    <p>Ingresar</p>
    <img src="assets/images/imgslide/slideb1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <p>Ingresar</p>
    <img src="assets/images/imgslide/slideb1.jpg">
  </div>
```

Esta es la función:

```
function getlayer(){

  var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);        //get array index selector
  var layera = document.getElementById("layera");
  layera.innerHTML='<p>' + captiona[idx] + '</p> <img src="' + slidea[idx] + '">';
 };
```

Con un estilo del slider definido para  la clase class="slide"

En este momento solo estoy trabajando con el primer elemento y por ello definí un div id = "layera" a fin de hacer la sustitución de HTML en la función.

El resultado de la función es el siguiente; es decir lo que se genera es:

Hola!

y se inserta bien en la

```
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="layera"><p>Hola!</p> <img src="assets/images/imgslide/slidea2.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

Casi todo funciona solo que la imagen no esta tomando el estilo asignado por el slider al 100%, en los otros

```
.slider{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 568px;
}

.slider figure div{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.slider figure img{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

La galería (segundo caso y abajo del slider) tiene elementos div parecidos a:

```
        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filter hdpe">
            <a href="http://www.economista.com.mx" target="_blank"><img src=ropa\assets\images\parras_2400_800_.jpg class="img-responsive">
            <a><small>Conoce nuestras opciones</small></a>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filter hdpe">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
```

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Problema resuelto, gracias por su atención.

Comment: ¿Cómo resolviste el problema? ¿Podrías añadir una respuesta con lo que hiciste?